# pushUp Notification not too frequent and browser allow

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, notifications, push-notification

hello all i am using this code for browser/desktop PushUP Notification

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
 Notification.requestPermission();
 var notification = window.Notification || window.mozNotification ||      window.webkitNotification;
 notification.requestPermission(function(permission){});
  });function notifyMe(titleisthi,contentbody,linktoopen) {
  if (!Notification) {
 alert('Desktop notifications not available in your browser. Try Chromium.'); 
 return;
 }  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
 Notification.requestPermission();                
 else {
     var notification = new Notification(titleisthi, {
  icon: 'avator/small-icon.png',
  body: contentbody,
  });
 notification.onclick = function () {
 window.open(linktoopen);      
 };}}
```

The Problem is that this code sometimes sends many notifications or its too frequent can there be something which dosent sends more than 2  notification within 30 minutes. and also users dont need to allow the browser to receive the notification or not.

any help is appreciated.
i know sending notifications too frequently depends on my code or calling the function but i was wondering if there is something which can prevent them globally.